# WIX: Выполнение exe/dll до RemoveExistingProducts c повышенными правами

Tags: windowsinstaller, wix

Необходимо, чтобы **перед установкой/удалением продукта** срабатывал CustomAction (CA) или какая-нибудь сторонняя программа с повышенными правами

1. Для того, чтобы CA выполнился с повышенными правами, необходимо задать два параметра

> Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"

При этом все такие CA должны быть расположены между в InstallExecuteSequence между InstallInitialize и InstallFinalize

2. Есть такой параметр как [RemoveExistingProducts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/removeexistingproducts-action), которые удаляет предыдущую версию. Он может располагается в 4 местах. Первые 2 пункта по ссылке удаляют все файлы и ставят все файлы заново, последние два сначала обновляют файлы,а потом удаляют старые.
3. Сейчас RemoveExistingProducts у нас расположен после InstallInitialize, после создания CA его тоже нужно разместить после InstallInitialize, но при этом нельзя задать выполнение CA раньше,чем RemoveExistingProducts, так как в документации есть вот оговорка "any actions that generate execution script.". Сейчас смотрим документации по RemoveExistingProducts эти 4 пункта и отсюда вывод:

   3.1. Перед InstallValidate нас не устроит, так как CA надо располагать после него

   3.2. Располагать после InstallInitialize не получится, так как перед ним нельзя выполнить никаких скриптов с правами

   3.3 Остальные пункты нам не подходят, так как инсталлятор не обновляет файлы сторонних разработчиков, где не указано версии, а у нас их куча

Теперь собственно вопросы.

Существуют ли иные механизмы, к примеру,можно ли запускать CA без привелегий и сделать так,чтобы он сам у себя запрашивал? (получается 2 раза за инсталяцию принимать запрос UAC) 
Или же какие-нибудь другие маневры вне моего понимания?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как одно из решений - запустить через CA exe в отдельном процессе и его слушать. Процесс сам себе будет представлять права с помощью манифеста. Как минус - за время установки будет несколько запросов повышения привелегии